# Enabling Hardware Acceleration for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It's my first time looking at android studio and I came across a problem when trying to run my first app. I get this error:

[image]

I have tried to navigate to here to install it but I don't have a folder named intel for some reason:

```
USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

I have also disabled `enable hardware-assisted virtualization` In avast because I read online that it can cause some issues when installing it.

Anyone know why I cant find the file to install it or know an alternative way of doing so?

**Edit 1:** I'm running x64bit windows 10 and trying to run my apps on Nexus 5 if that has any help.

**Edit 2:** I have now got the Intel folder and have the `exe` I need to install it but I get this error now:

[image]

When I check my bios however, it is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not downloaded HAXM with the SDK Manager. Start the SDK Manager and install it.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out then but now I get another error when trying to install it. See my edit 2.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after I posted my answer. I'm actually trying to see if I can replicate it and figure out a fix.

Comment: C:\Users\jamesk93\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: device fd:924
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Comment: ^ Thats what I get now when I run a simple app.

Comment: Increase the available RAM to HAXM. It has 1024MB allocated to it, but the emulator image requires 1536MB. Increase it to 2GB.

Comment: How do I open the config window again? I set it as default when setting it up. Do I have to reinstall?

Comment: Yes, you need to run the installer again.

Comment: Getting the following now: http://imgur.com/SOR3R35 The error in red just keeps looping till I shut down the emulator which is blank

Comment: Came on my computer again this morning and for some reason, its all working now.Thanks for your help yesterday